# AutoIt select item from menubar

Tags: automation, autoit, menubar, hyperterminal

i want to build some automation code that will select some item from a menubar of minimized (or non-active) window.

I have tried to do it with ControlSend function by sending some keys like alt and directions, but it's not working...

See my example:

I want to select the item "Select All", for this i wrote this code:

```
WinWaitActive("")
Send("{ALTDOWN}{ALTUP}{RIGHT}{ENTER}{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}")
```

The code above works good, but i want that it will work when the window is not active, so i wrote this line:

```
ControlSend("", "", "Term Class1", "{ALTDOWN}{ALTUP}{RIGHT}{ENTER}{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}")
```

This is not working for me, do you have some idea how can i implement it?

Answer (score -1):

I too was trying to work with minimized windows but have since switched from windows so i wont be able to test things out for you. I have been told (and from experience) that you cant use control send (or the mouse click alternative which is called "control click")  on applications that do not come stock with windows (applications that dont come with the computer, to put it simply).

However i came upon this (https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/7112-minimized-clicking-great-for-game-bots/) which seems to be a 3rd party add in that lets you do just that, i tried using it but could not make it fit my needs. Perhaps you can, I would try to get it working for you but again, i dumped windows. The above link is the best candidate i have found, and by far the most promising after i searched and tested for about a month a while back, Good Luck.

EDIT:  As always, i do not promise anything from the above link, you use it at your own risk.